# while loop in python not updating

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, numbers, pyautogui

my while loop not updating and see the up coming numbers

```
while keyboard.is_pressed('q') == False:

if pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('Pipe.png', confidence = 0.7) != None:
    pipePos = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('Pipe.png', confidence = 0.7)
    PipeYpos = pipePos.y
    print(pipePos)
    print("I can see it The Pipe")
    t = 1
else:
    print("I am unable to see it The Pipe")
    t = 0
    
if pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('BirdV2.png', confidence = 0.5) != None:
    birdpos = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('BirdV2.png', confidence = 0.5)
    birdyPos = birdpos.y
    print(birdpos)
    print("I can see it The Bird")
    t = 1
else:
    print("I am unable to see it The BIRD")
    t = 0
```

here is the problem

```
while birdyPos >= PipeYpos and keyboard.is_pressed('q') == False and t == 1 and PipeYpos != 0:
    print("Pipe > bird")
    click(1384 ,1235)
    birdyPos = 0
    PipeYpos = 0
```

when the loop get the birdyPos >= PipeYpos it wouldn't forget

it will keep going
i want it to stop and make sure the numbers are correct and looping again

Comment: You're setting both variables to `0`, so `birdyPos >= PipeYpos` will stay true because they're equal.

Comment: But the loop should stop immediately because `PipeYpos != 0` is false.

Comment: maybe first use `print()` to see which part of code is executed and what you have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is doing.